# Open a terminal from a Crontab

Tags: bash, cron, crontab

How do I get a gnome-terminal window to open from a crontab?

I have tried this:

```
    * * * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal 

    * * * * * source /home/user_name/.bashrc ; /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

    * * * * * source /home/user_name/.profile ; /usr/bin/gnome-terminal

    * * * * * source /home/user_name/.bashrc ; /home/user_name/bin/opengnometerminal.sh
```

None of these seem to work.

Comment: Haven't used X in awhile but you probably need `DISPLAY` set in your environment.

Comment: You could use cron to touch a file somewhere and use an inotify script (which is running in your X session) to watch the file and launch a terminal when the file changes...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I want to send myself a message at a certain time. I will find another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, safely. cron jobs run independent of the desktop session where X is running, therefore you can't do this without causing security violations.

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try Python-notify to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 5):

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Though this is not really a robust solution since there's no guarantees that X server will be on :0.

Comment: There's also no guarantees that the user crond runs as will have the X auth cookie.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried that on my system: <code> Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: </code> I think I will try Python-notify.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried that on my system: [code] Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display: [/code] I think I will try Python-notify.

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu add in crontab the command:

exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator /home/user/show-my-script-in-window-terminal.sh

Comment: What is ``/home/user/show-my-script-in-window-terminal.sh``?